# Finding name of a process?

Tags: terminal, macos

I'm doing a project for school and it involves running a java program which sometimes crashes. In order to kill the unresponsive program, I'll go to my dock, right click on the program and press "Force Quit":

[image: Dock]

The program it kills has a window with a title "Planet Wars Visualizer", and the top menu for the program in the top left says "CLViewer":

[image: Window]

Instead of having to press "Force Quit" every time, I want to just use the `killall <name>` command. However, when I go to my activity monitor I don't see any processes with the names "Java", "Planet Wars Visualizer", or "CLViewer". Even when I try `killall` with those names I just get `No matching processes belonging to you were found`.

How can I find out the actual name of the process just by the clues I have?

Comment: What do you get if you issue the command `ps -a`?

Comment: Here: https://imgur.com/a/tNBFy

Comment: Please *paste* the text into your answer.  It's difficult to see on a mobile device.  You can pipe the output directly to the clipboard with the command `ps -a | pbcopy`

Answer (score 1):

When the program goes unresponsive, open Activity Monitor and see if a process is followed by a message in red which says unresponsive. You can get the name of the process from there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pkill` command.

From the man page ([`man pkill`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkill.1.html))

> The pkill command searches the process table on the running system and
>   signals all processes that match the criteria given on the command
>   line.

Before issuing the `pkill` command, it's useful to test it out by using the `pgrep` command first (from man page:  "find or signal processes by name").

Once you are certain that `pgrep` is finding the processes you are interested in killing, issue the `pkill` command.